# Longest Path in Graph's Spanning Tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

Today, we learned in university basics of Graphs. We learned about trees and aboout Greedy Algorithm to find minimal spanning tree of graph. I will visualize my question in this concrete graph.

[image: Basic Graph]

By using Greedy Algorithm you can find different minimal spanning trees :

For example :
**Minimal Spanning Tree 1**

[image: Minimal Spanning Tree1]

**Minimal Spanning Tree 2**

[image: Minimal Spanning Tree2]

My question is about length of maximum path distance in both spanning trees:

$P_1 = \{42, 21, 10, 03, 36 , 65, 57\}  $

$P_2 = \{42, 20, 03, 36, 65, 57\} $

$ |P_1| = 8 $

$ |P_2| = 7 $

Both of those examples are spanning tree but my intuition tells me , if there is shorter way from one end to another , that the graph is somehow superior, more optimalized. I don't know how to name this property so I'm asking, if there is any term, and what it is of this property of graph?

Thank you so much for answers

Comment: I think you mean you want the spanning tree with the smallest diameter.

Comment: It is called diameter so?

Comment: It's called diameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is the [diameter](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphDiameter.html) of the minimal spanning tree. The diameter of a graph is the largest distance between any two points, which in your scenario of a tree, is the longest path.

It is uncertain what greedy algorithm you are using, but it appears you might be using [Prim's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm#Proof_of_correctness) which is always optimal for connected graphs so it might not make as much sense for the graph to be more superior, optimised, without defining what you meant by those words.

Comment: No , it was Kruskal Greedy Algorithm but it doesn't matter which algorithm I used. Important question is if the Spanning Tree with smallest diameter is somehow better that other spanning tree with bigger diameter. Imagine this scenario: You have to create roads between all of villages with smallest cost possible. So you use algorithm to find spanning tree. But the tree where two furthest towns are closer to each other ( smaller diameter) is more optimized than other solutions. Am I right??

Comment: I presume you meant a smaller diameter implies a smaller average pairwise distance? In this case, consider a path with a star affixed to it. You should be able to show that the ratio of the diameter to the average pairwise distance can be arbitrary large.